# How to properly use preloads and window.api calls in electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, ipc, preloadjs

I am having trouble using a render.js file to write "api" calls from the rendered html page's javascript.

main.js new BrowserWindow function includes:

```js
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: false, // is default value after Electron v5
        contextIsolation: true, // protect against prototype pollution
        enableRemoteModule: false, // turn off remote
        preload: "preload.js" // use a preload script  
    },
```

preload.js:

```js
const { ipcRenderer, contextBridge } = require('electron')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    "api", {
        send: (channel, data) => {
            let validChannels = ["login"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
            }
        },
        receive: (channel, func) => {
            let validChannels = ["fromMain"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args));
            }
        }
    }
);
```

passwordPage.js linked in passwordPage.html:

```js
document.getElementById("login").addEventListener('click', function() {
    window.api.send("login", "test");
})
```

error in console of passwordPage:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions):

> The value should be the **absolute file path** to the script.

Try to use `` `${__dirname}/preload.js` `` or something equal.